# $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are roots of cubic equation $x^3+4x-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of the equation $x^3+4x-1=0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha+1},\frac{1}{\beta+1},\frac{1}{\gamma+1}$ are the roots of the equation

$\displaystyle 6x^3-7x^2+3x-1=0$. Then value of $\displaystyle \frac{(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}{\alpha^2}+\frac{(\gamma+1)(\alpha+1)}{\beta^2}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)}{\gamma^2}=$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Given $x=\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of the equation $x^3+4x-1=0$, Then

$x^3+4x-1 = (x-\alpha)\cdot(x-\beta)\cdot (x-\gamma)$

put $x=-1$, we get $(1+\alpha)(1+\beta)(1+\gamma) = 6$

Now $\displaystyle \frac{(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}{\alpha^2}+\frac{(\gamma+1)(\alpha+1)}{\beta^2}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)}{\gamma^2} = 6\left\{\frac{1}{(\alpha+1)\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{(\beta+1)\beta^2}+\frac{1}{(\gamma+1)\gamma^2}\right\}$

Now how can I solve after that,

Help required

thanks

Comment: There is something missing from your question. The equation in the sentence starting with «Then value of...» is incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation leads us$$\displaystyle \frac{(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}{\alpha^2}+\frac{(\gamma+1)(\alpha+1)}{\beta^2}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)}{\gamma^2} $$$$= 6\left\{\frac{1}{(\alpha+1)\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{(\beta+1)\beta^2}+\frac{1}{(\gamma+1)\gamma^2}\right\}.$$
Here, by [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), notice that
$$\frac{7}{6}=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}+\frac{1}{\beta+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma+1}=\frac{(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)+2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+3}{(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}.$$
Since $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0,$ we have
$$(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)=6.$$

Noting that your last $\{\}$ equals to
$$\frac{({\alpha}^3+{\beta}^3+{\gamma}^3)+({\alpha}^2+{\beta}^2+{\gamma}^2)}{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)},$$ we can use
$${\alpha}^3+{\beta}^3+{\gamma}^3=3\alpha\beta\gamma+(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)({\alpha}^2+{\beta}^2+{\gamma}^2-\alpha\beta-\beta\gamma-\gamma\alpha).$$
with
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0,\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha=4,\alpha\beta\gamma=1$$
and
$${\alpha}^2+{\beta}^2+{\gamma}^2=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-2(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha).$$
Now you'll be able to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $x^{3} + 4x - 1 = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$, we note that, by the theory of symmetric polynomials,

$$0 = \alpha+\beta+\gamma = s_{1}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$$

$$4 = \alpha\beta + \beta\gamma+\alpha\gamma = s_{2}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$$

$$1 = \alpha\beta\gamma = s_{3}(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$$

As suggested by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, we can observe immediately that the expression

$\displaystyle \frac{(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}{\alpha^2}+\frac{(\gamma+1)(\alpha+1)}{\beta^2}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)}{\gamma^2}$

is symmetric in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, i.e. it is invariant under permuting $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Therefore, I would put everything under a common denominator. The numerator then becomes

$$\beta^{2}\gamma^{2}(\beta\gamma+\gamma+\beta+1) + \alpha^{2}\gamma^{2}(\alpha\gamma+\gamma+\alpha+1) + \alpha^{2}\beta^{2}(\alpha\beta + \alpha + \beta+1)$$

It can easily be seen that this is a symmetric polynomial in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ as well. It can therefore be written in terms of $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}$. The denominator is $\alpha^{2}\beta^{2}\gamma^{2} = s_{3}^{2} = 1^{2} = 1$. If you would like more information on how to write the numerator in terms of the symmetric polynomials, please comment and I'd be happy to add information.

Comment: Notice that the initial expression is in fact a symmtric rational function. Its denominator is plainly symmetric, so its numerator is also symmetric.

Comment: Indeed @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, though I think the process of rewriting the expression in terms of the symmetric polynomials is more transparent with this small modification. (I'm not sure even sure what the canonical symmetric rational functions are, as it were - is there a better solution I'm missing?)

Comment: Not really. But you could ascertain that everything was symmetric from the begining, without doing any manipulations. I was midly complaining to the way your answer is written, as it deduces symmetry after some rearrangent andonly of the numerator :D

Comment: Haha, fair enough. I'll make a note of it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the second equation, $$\frac6{(\alpha+1)^3}-\frac7{(\alpha+1)^2}+\frac3{\alpha+1}-1=0$$

$$\implies 6-7(\alpha+1)+3(\alpha+1)^2-(\alpha+1)^3=0\iff \alpha^3+4\alpha-1=0$$

So, both equations are actually equivalent

$\displaystyle y=\frac{(\beta+1)(\gamma+1)}{\alpha^2}=\frac{\beta\gamma+\beta+\gamma+1}{\alpha^2}=\frac{\alpha\beta\gamma+\alpha(\beta+\gamma)+\alpha}{\alpha^3}=\frac{1-\alpha^2+\alpha}{1-4\alpha} $ as  $\alpha^3=1-4\alpha$

$\displaystyle\implies \alpha^2-\alpha(1+4y)+y-1=0\  \ \  \ (1)$

$\displaystyle y=\frac6{\alpha^2(\alpha+1)}=\frac6{(1-4\alpha)+\alpha^2}$

$\displaystyle\implies \alpha^2y-4y\alpha+y-6=0\ \  \ \ (2) $

Solve $(1),(2)$ for  $\alpha^2,\alpha$ 
and use $\alpha^2=(\alpha)^2$ to eliminate $\alpha$ and form a cubic equation in $y$ whose roots are $\displaystyle y_1,y_2,y_3$(say)

Now use Vieta's formulas to find the required $\displaystyle y_1+y_2+y_3$

We can also find $\displaystyle y_1y_2+y_2y_3+y_3y_1$ from here if need be

Comment: I suspect that your calculation would be wrong.

Comment: The point where you use $\iff$.

Comment: @mathlove, please have a look into the edited answer

Comment: I like your argument. But notice that $(1)$ should be ${\alpha}^2-\alpha(1+4y)+y-1=0.$

Comment: @mathlove, thanks for patience. The accuracy of my calculation is diminishing day by day